# SwiftUI: Randomize frame height of Rectangles within a ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to randomize the height of `Rectangle`s within a `ForEach` loop. How can I do this using the `.frame(height: ?)` modifier? Is this possible or should I not use a `ForEach` loop?

```
struct SoundwaveView: View {

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 16) {
        ForEach(1..<20) { index in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 6, height: 50)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(3)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here's an image of the desired outcome I'd like:
[image]

Comment: Why not use the following `Int.random(in: minHeight...maxHeight)`?

Comment: That worked, thanks Timmy! You should post this in the form of an answer so you can get credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Timmy's answer below my original question

```
struct SoundwaveView: View {

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 16) {
        ForEach(1..<20) { index in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 6, height: CGFloat.random(in: 5...60))
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `CGFloat`. It's implicit.